# Solution for payment gateway with multiple sellers

Tags: ecommerce, payments, payment-gateway

I'm looking for a payment gateway that can be used in a website with multiple sellers. Let's say that depending on the purchased item, a given seller/merchant should receive the money.

Would that be possible using only one "master merchant" account that would act as a "distributor" of funds for several "sub-merchants"?

Does any well established privider (paypal, worldpay, auth.net, etc) supports this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/adaptive_payments)

> Adaptive Payments offers a number of
>   features, including:
>
> Pay anyone with an email address. Make
>   payments to another person as long as
>   they have an email address or mobile
>   phone number, with or without a PayPal
>   account. Recipients without a PayPal
>   account can create one in minutes.
>
> Receive payments from anyone.
>   Customers, with or without a PayPal
>   account, can make a payment as long as
>   they have an email address.
>
> Pre-approved payments. Customers can
>   pre-approve future payments.
>
> Disbursements. Make payments from any
>   of your available funding sources. Use
>   disbursements to enable payroll
>   payments, rebate payments, reward
>   payments, and more.
>
> Simple payments. As always, make a
>   simple one-to-one payment.
>
> Chained payments. Send a payment to
>   one individual, who in turn shares the
>   payment with multiple individuals.
>
> **Split payments. Divide a payment among
>   a number of individuals.**
>
> Retrieve Foreign Exchange rates. Send
>   a list of amounts and currencies and
>   get the converted amounts for the
>   requested currencies.
>
> Refund payments: Refund payments made
>   through an application.
>
> Embedded payments: Reduce checkout
>   friction and increase conversion rates
>   with inline checkout.